# Long press Toolbar menu icon show gray text background

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu, android-touch-event

I have Toolbar and I have menu items with icons and descriptions on it.

When I do a long press on that icon it appears a pop up with a description for that menu item.

The problem is that text in that pop up has a different color than the background color.

[image: id]

Here is **toolbar.xml** file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/ToolbarThemeMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/toolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Here is the code for **toolbarStyle** from **styles.xml**

```
  <style name="ToolbarThemeMain" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textLight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecondary</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
  </style>
```

**colorPrimary** is that green color from the image above.

How to solve this issue and remove the gray text background and have the same green as colorPrimary?

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to the toolbar at all , you have to change your popup and as far as i know make your own popup layout , i dont know if you have one or not but i put the codes down here anyway :

first call this popup when you long press on the icon :

```
private void setPopUpWindow() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_menu, null);
    mypopupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, 50, 20, true);//set the size of your popup here (remember you can suite the sizes based on the phones's width and height)
    mypopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mypopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    mypopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));//this is for disappearing the popup after somewhere else has touched
}
```

now you can change your popup just the way you want in the pop_up_menu.xml in the layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text here"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

feel free to ask any questions... :)

Comment: This could work, but I think that there should be an easier and more elegant solution to override text background color for a menu items.